# How do I convert this parametric expression to an implicit one

Tags: functions, parametric

I have:

$$x=5+8 \cos \theta$$
$$y=4+8 \sin \theta$$

With $ -\frac {3\pi}4 \le \theta \le 0$

If I wanted to write that implicitly, how would I do it? I get that it's a circle, and I can easily write the circle implicitly, but I'm not sure how to convert the domain from $ -\frac {3\pi}4 \le \theta \le 0$ to a suitable domain in x and y.

I can think of a way to do it that would involve using the $Min$ function, but is that allowed in an implicit representation?

Answer (score 1):

Use that $\exists \theta : (v,w) = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta) \iff v^2 + w^2 = 1$.

You immediately get that the parametric curve is a part of the curve defined by
the implicit equation
$$
\left(\frac{x-5}8\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y-4}8\right)^2 = 1$$

To get only the part that you want, you must also make sure that $-\frac{3\pi}4\le \theta\le  0$, which is equivalent to
$$
\cos \theta \ge -\frac 12, \sin\theta< 0
$$

and then you get the equation

\begin{cases}
\left(\frac{x-5}8\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y-4}8\right)^2 = 1\\
\frac{x-5}8 \ge -\frac 12\\
\frac{y-4}8 \le 0
\end{cases}

Comment: How did you get the cos >= -1/2, sin<0 part?

Comment: @CameronBall just take a look at the (x,y) plan to figure out.

Comment: Looking at this, I can't figure out where the -1/2 came from. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Sine_cosine_one_period.svg/2000px-Sine_cosine_one_period.svg.png

Comment: nvm, got it looking at a unit circle.

Comment: Actually thinking about it more, I still don't understand. sin(theta) < 0 makes sense, but I feel like that -1/2 should be -sqrt(2)/2, what am I missing?

Comment: there is a mistake with this value indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Just compute the range of $x,y$, or using the geometric meaning of polar coordinate, draw a picture to see how $x,y$ changes on the circle when $\theta$ changes.

The result is $x\in[5-4\sqrt{2},13],y\in[-4,4]$, where $x,y$ satisfies $(x-5)^2+(y-4)^4=8^2$.

Comment: This isn't enough, because it also describes a full circle also, while his parametric equations describe 3/4 of a circle. They both have the same ranges, but they are not the same